# Android studio cannot read my sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am doing my university project which requires creating a database. I created a database in DB Browser for SQLite and it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D2Ir.png)

but when I copied this into Android Studio it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsBRS.png)

Android Studio reads my Setting table normally, but when it comes to my WokroutDays table it says that I don't have this table.

This is the print out of an error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.seniorapplication, PID: 24122
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: WorkoutDays (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO WorkoutDays(Day) VALUES('1602576762730');, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
```

or maybe it is the problem with my saving method saveDay:

```
public void saveDay(String value){
     SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
     String query = String.format("INSERT INTO WorkoutDays(Day) VALUES('%s');",value);
     db.execSQL(query);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try reinstalling your app and building again? Because sqlite tables modifies in app when it freshly installs.